# SPLUNK : .Message.value()]: A string literal was expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, splunk, splunk-query

I want to execute this code in Splunk using "| dbxquery":

`(select top 1 a.Message.value ('(//Transaction[@transactionID=sql:column("t.Txn_Ref_Num")]/LifeSupportNotification/LifeSupportData/Status)[1]', 'varchar(50)')`

but gets error: "Message_Archive.Message.value()]: A string literal was expected"

Been looking for solution for a while now.

Edit (here's the code)

```
    | dbxquery query="select
    'Elec' as Fuel,
    t.txn_ref_num as 'Transaction_Id',
    t.Transaction_Id as T_ID,

t.XML_transaction_Type as 'Transaction_Type',
t.cust_ref_num as 'NMI',
(select top 1 a.Message.value('(//Transaction [ @transactionID=sql:column("t.Txn_Ref_Num")]/LifeSupportNotification/LifeSupportData/Status)[1]', 'varchar(50)')  
    from MDHElec.dbo.MDH_Message_Archive a with (nolock) , MDHElec.dbo.ArchivePath p with (nolock)
where a.Message_Archive_Id=p.Message_Archive_Id and p.TransactionID=t.Txn_Ref_Num and a.Flow='REC') as 'LifeSupportStatus',
t.date_created as 'Timestamp',
mt.master_transaction_status as Status,
'Outbound' as 'Direction',
case
when mt.Master_Transaction_Status = 'PACN' then 'NULL'
when mte.Exception_Id is not null and t.XML_Transaction_Type not in ('TransactionAcknowledgement') and t.Transaction_Id = mte.Transaction_Id then 'Reject'
else 'Accept' end as 'TackStatus'
,mt.Date_Last_Updated
from MDHElec.dbo.transactions t with (nolock)
join MDHElec.dbo.Master_Transaction mt with (nolock) on mt.Master_Txn_Id = t.Master_Txn_Id
left join MDHElec.dbo.Master_Txn_Exception mte with (nolock) on mt.Master_Txn_Id = mte.Master_Txn_Id
where t.xml_transaction_type = 'LifeSupportNotification'
and t.Source_System = 'KRK'
and t.date_created >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
order by t.Date_Created desc" connection="MDH_PRD"

|table *
```

Comment: Pretty sure a splunk query has nothing to do with SQL server.

Comment: What does your hole SPL look like?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/DBX/latest/DeployDBX/Commands), the fact you have multiple types of quote marks is most likely causing the error you're seeing.

Your excised query:

```
(select top 1 a.Message.value ('(//Transaction[@transactionID=sql:column("t.Txn_Ref_Num")]/LifeSupportNotification/LifeSupportData/Status)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Note you have both single (`'`) *and* double (`"`) quotes in the string.

Per the `dbxquery` page on Docs.Splunk, the query you send is supposed to be encased in double quotes:

> **query**
> **Syntax**: `query=<string>`
> **Description**: A SQL query. You can also use a URL-encoded SQL query, but you must percent-encode all spaces (%20).

And one of the examples shown:

> `dbxquery query="select * from actor where actor_id > ? and actor_name = ?" connection="mysql" params="3,BOB"`

The two other examples shown:

> `| dbxquery query="SELECT actor_id, first_name as fname, last_name as lname, last_update FROM actor" connection="mySQL"`

> `| dbxquery query="SELECT actor_id, first_name as fname, last_name as lname, last_update FROM actor" connection="mySQL" maxrows=100`

Comment: I have added the whole code